# Message is not sent to Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, c++, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I can read the messages that come from my extension, but not able to send a message from my c++ native app to my chrome extension. I am using Win 8 64bit.
The chrome log simply does not report any error, so no info from there.

Here is my code:

```
void SendMessage(string msg){
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_BINARY);
    unsigned int len =  msg.length();
    cout.write((char*)&len,4);
    //cout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&len),4);
    std::cout << msg << flush;
}

string ReadMessage(){
    string msg = "";
    std::cout.setf( std::ios_base::unitbuf );
    unsigned int ch;//, len = 0;

    //another way to get the length
    _Uint32t len = 0;
    cin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&len) ,4);

    //  read len number of characters as the message
    for (int i=0; i < len; i++) {
        ch = getchar();
        msg += ch;
    }
    return msg;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //reading messages from the extension
    string msg = ReadMessage();
    //here i write the msg into log and it's there.

    //sending a message
    SendMessage ("sent by C++");

    return 0;
}
```

What's wrong with this code? I have tried many combinations for writing the message. Also, I have tried with or without that _setmode function, but still not working.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please show your whole application. Did you correctly read all data from stdin before trying to send data to stdout? Have you also followed all debugging tips at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#native-messaging-debugging

Comment: Rob, yes I have already read the message without any problem. One thing that I am gonna check is endianness (small and big) where it might cause a problem, where I write the message length (which actually I am not sure how to set small or big endian). Otherwise, I have adhered to everything in the protocol.